# Assigning vectors without copying them

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have two `std::vector` with several `std::unordered_set` inside. However, one of the vector will be replacing the other throughout the execution, like this:

```
vector1 = ...
vector2 = ...
// some operations
vector1 = vector2
vector2 = std::vector<...>
```

Is there a way of achieving this without having to copy the contents of the vectors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since C++11 you can [move assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) them:

```
vector1 = std::move(vector2); // move vector2 to vector1
vector2 = std::vector<...>;   // move the temporary vector to vector2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) to exchange the contents

Comment: But that copies the vector. I was looking for a solution that would not envolve wasting time with something that I don't need.

Comment: Swap moves, not copies